# How can I tell if a unit is ducking or standing?

Tags: frozen-synapse

I have a very poor short term memory (4 concussions, yaaaay), so sometimes I forget if I've given an order to a unit to change its stance in the past or not. I can't always tell based on the pose of the unit because when it's mostly behind the cover of a full height wall, it's difficult to see.

Is there any trick or shortcut or some sort of unit status window I'm missing, or is it actually just a matter of remembering?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a little icon next to the weapon the unit is using. If it is there they are ducking, if not they are standing.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I usually tell:

Ducking units move at a slower pace than standing units, so just do a single simulated run and have them move in some direction.

Either way, the order to 'stand' doesn't seem to take up any time, so as a precaution, I tend to give all my guys the order to 'stand' and to cancel aim if I want them to move unless I want them to maintain aim.